# Код ответа сервера

Tags: java, android

Есть код отправки гет запроса на сервер. Как сделать условие if(код ответа == код)?

```
 public class JSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        while (true) {
            onCreate();
            try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (Код ответа? == код) {
```

}

Comment: Вы усложняете себе жизнь обрабатывая все руками, но это ваш выбор.  Вам нужно распарсить первую строку и получить статус ответа. первая строка должна иметь следующий вид `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: Советую сразу почитать про OkHttp и Retrofit